# cortex m3, stm32L1XX bit-banding

Tags: c, stm32, cortex-m, iar, bit-banding

I'm following the guide given at  micromouseonline . com/2010/07/14/bit-banding-in-the-stm32 . I'm using `IAR EWARM` and `Cortex M3`. Everything works fine but I'm not able to set the bits in a given address. Im using `STM32L151xD` and `IAR EWARM` compiler.

This is how they define the functions

```
#define RAM_BASE 0x20000000
#define RAM_BB_BASE 0x22000000
#define Var_ResetBit_BB(VarAddr, BitNumber) (*(vu32 *) (RAM_BB_BASE | ((VarAddr - RAM_BASE) << 5) | ((BitNumber) << 2)) = 0)
#define Var_SetBit_BB(VarAddr, BitNumber) (*(vu32 *) (RAM_BB_BASE | ((VarAddr - RAM_BASE) << 5) | ((BitNumber) << 2)) = 1)
#define Var_GetBit_BB(VarAddr, BitNumber) (*(vu32 *) (RAM_BB_BASE | ((VarAddr - RAM_BASE) << 5) | ((BitNumber) << 2)))


#define varSetBit(var,bit) (Var_SetBit_BB((u32)&var,bit))
#define varGetBit(var,bit) (Var_GetBit_BB((u32)&var,bit))
```

the call is :

```
uint32_t flags;
varSetBit(flags,1);
```

however, the bit 1 in flags is always 0 if I see using a debugger. The flags is assumed to be 0 at first. So, all the bits in flags will be 0. However, when i use varSetBit(flags,1), the answer at bit 1 is 0 again. I dont think im doing anything wrong. Is it a compiler problem? am i missing some settings? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you misunderstand the purpose of the bit-banding feature.
With bit-banding, the application have access (read/write) to the micro-controller's registers bit by bit. This allows modifying a bit with a single store instruction instead of a read/modify/write sequence. For this to work, `stm32` devices (or more generally `Cortex M3` devices) have a specific address space where each bit of each register is mapped to a specific address.

Let's take an example, if you need to set the bit 3 of the register `FOO`:

- Without bit-banding, you would have to write the following code:

  `FOO = FOO | 0b100;`

This results from the assembler instructions in a load of the register `FOO`, a bit-wise `OR` operation and a store of the register `FOO`.

- With bit-banding, you write:

  `varSetBit(FOO, 3);`

which results to a simple store at the address computed by preprocessor from the `varSetBit` macro.

Now that is said, bit-banding only apply to the micro-controller's register. You can't use them to manipulate bits of your own variables as you do with your `flags` variable.

For more information read the [ARM application note](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0179b/CHDJHIDF.html)

Comment: This is correct; you can of course write your own macro to set a single bit in a user-defined variable but it will still be a read-modify-write operation and the macro simply makes it easier to see what is going on.